# Iterating in the users CSV file - will it create any issues?

Tags: csv, jmeter

We have a JMeter script that runs around 1 minute from start to end. It uses a users CSV file to get the user login id. Our target is to run the script for 900 virtual users for 20 minutes. We decided 2s per user would be a good ramp-up time.

To avoid any bottlenecks on the JMeter, we have set up 6 JMeter slaves and decided to split 150 users in each. Now, each slave Jmeter machine has it's own unique 300 users' list.

But what is concerning us is: to allow the script to run for 20 minutes after the ramp up (900 VU * 2 seconds/user = 1800 sec = 30 minutes) we need to execute the script for 50 minutes. So, we decided to iterate through the script 50 times. Now, that will use same user id repeatedly and we think at some point, different user thread will be using the same user (user id).

Is there a way to avoid this? I know we could give really long list of unique users to each slave (e.g., 4000 unique users for each JMeter slave, instead of 300) and make sure no two threads use the same user id, but creating that many users is a challenge.

Any other suggestions?

Will two tread share the session? In reality, if I login using the same user in two different tabs in a browser, logging out from one tab, automatically logs me out from the other. But what will happen for JMeter therads?

I hope my question makes sense to you, apologies if it does not.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you added Loop Controller to your test plan?

Comment: No, I'm iterating by checking 'Forever' checkbox in the Thread Group. To stop, i've chose 'Stop Thread on EOF' for the users.csv file.

Comment: Sorry, my last part of the previous comment is wrong. Can't update it: We didn't use 'stop thread on EOF' for the users CSV file. We actually manually stopped the test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually web applications use [Cookies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie) to distinguish authenticated users from each other and from the non-authenticated ones

So by adding [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://blazemeter.com/blog/using-http-cookie-manager-jmeter-not-cookie-jar) to your Test Plan and having "Clear cookies each iteration" box checked you'll be able to simulate this LogIn -> Logout behaviour and will be able to narrow down the number of unique username/password combinations required.

Remember that **iteration** is something which is defined on [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) level, ones, triggered by i.e. [Loop Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller) won't clear cookies in the Cookie Manager.

Comment: Thanks Dmitri. I already had HTTP Cookie manger added with clear cookie each iteration enabled. Also, was iterating from thread group, didn't add any loop controllers. However, since we are running the iterations 'forever' with recycling on EOF on the users CSV file, I fear that in a situation where two users are logged in with the same user id (possibility is really low), it may cause data inconsistency in the database side. Anyways, we tripled the users' list size in each slave to avoid such cases (even lower the possibility).

Comment: Just provide unique set of users to each slave and that should be it

Answer (score 1):

Dmitri T's answer works as long as each thread takes roughly the same amount of time. It's possible that a few threads finish quickly, particularly if you have 'Start Next Thread Loop' set on error. Theoretically your scenario is possible, but as long as you manage your Cookies correctly, you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks RowlandB. Yes, we applied the techniques that Dmitri mentioned. Also tripled the size of the unique users' list in each slave to avoid such scenarios.